# Can Wordpress handle more than 100 pages?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm thinking of hosting over 100 pages on Wordpress and I'm worried about the performance. It's very easy to create a website with Wordpress, but is it able to handle it? What do you think?

Comment: This is too broad a question. How can we tell what the performance would be? We don't know the hardware you're running on or anything about the content.

Comment: It's no problem. I'm working on templates with over 100 pages. If the server you're hosting it on is good enough then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The web site is in shared hosting.. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

It's true Wordpress doesn't handle Pages as good as Posts, but with 100 you should be fine.
This is mostly due to the fact that pages use a different mechanism to handle URL's and are hierarchical, as reported [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/performance-issues-with-too-many-static-pages) that is enough to make a different impact on performance.

Wordpress has [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization) about Performance but doesn't state exactly the amount it starts to lag, that is because it will depend on the hardware you're running your website on.

If by pages you mean posts, I recently worked with a site that had +21k posts and there were no problems on that end.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical post types (like pages) can cause memory issues, [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15459) is the relevant Trac ticket. See also [this blog post](http://jkleinschmidt.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/lesson-learned-hierarchical-custom-post-types-dont-scale-well/).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can handle n number of pages.It is obvious that on every request by a user only one page is given in response and not all pages,hence you don't need to worry about website performance while considering number of pages...but If you do complex tasks in single page and user(or many users are) is accessing that page again and again than throughput will decrease and that will be for that page only,not for whole site.
 Do not think about website performance on number of pages.